# angular material placeholders and input/textarea style

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to use angular material for contact form but I have problem to change styles of input fields and placeholders or labels when is not on focus. I made [codepen](http://codepen.io/sasinjo/pen/OWEOoQ) and if you look there placeholders are grey. I want them to be green, change fonts to any other, and to make good position for them using padding or everything else.

I try solution as

```
md-input-container.md-default-theme label,   
md-input-container.md-default-theme .md-placeholder {  
    color: #FDFE67 !important; 
}
```

but nothing happened. I can't figure out how to change this and I didn't find any solution on internet.

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I added this piece of code there and it works

```
md-input-container.md-icon-float>label
{
  color: green
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/muzic12freakzz/pen/apKEOm

This is just a starting point. You can add more styles to it.

Comment: great, it works, I spent all day yesterday and didn't figure out

Comment: How I can also change position of placeholders, I want to not to be right to the edge

Comment: You can try something like this http://codepen.io/muzic12freakzz/pen/apKEOm

Comment: doesn't work on top, just on left, how to move placeholder from top of field?

Comment: And also my placeholders are not red when field is invalid?

Comment: And also when type something in field and go to another field placeholder change color to grey and I don't want that.